# How to take screenshot of a foreground appllication (like music) when screen is locked?

Tags: ios

I am fairly new to iOS. I need your help.

Is is possible to take screenshot of an application (lets say Music) which is running in the foreground and when iOS device's screen is locked using a program? If so, can you please let me know the code correspondingly. (This is for personal work only)

Comment: So you want to take a screen shot of something not currently displayed by the screen ?

Comment: Yes. In the above case, music will be playing and we will be able to hear the audio even though screen is locked. Now I want to capture the music player screen when device is locked and audio playback is going on..

Answer (score 0):

The iOS APIs for taking screenshots are private, which means that you cannot programmatically take a screen shot of the phone. Also, since iOS apps are sandboxed, you do not have access to the Music app (or any other app), so you cannot capture an image of the view being presented.

However, if the user takes a screenshot, you can access that screen shot using PhotoKit by getting the latest image in the Screenshots smart album.